# How to retrieve multiple records from table?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have a table having data.

```
id type
1  max
1  sam
1  rom
2  jak
```

I want to retrieve all the `type` where `id=1;`

```
if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *aRecord = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];
                NSLog (@"%@",aRecord);
            }
```

this statement retrive me only the last record. How can i get all the records?

```
how to catch these records in the variable. I am using aRecord but it store only last record. So this is the main concern
```

Comment: Use a wrapper.  It's *so* much easier: http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb or http://github.com/schwa/TouchSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql ro do this is simply:

```
select * from <table_name> where id = 1
```

do something like this:

```
NSMutableString *myRecords = [NSMutableString initWithString:@""];

if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {   
            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSString *aRecord = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];        

                myRecords = [myRecords stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",arecord]];                
                NSLog (@"%@",aRecord);   
                }
```

As Peter Hosey points out in the comments, this will give you one string with all three records separated by a space.  You probably want to populate an array with these records instead.

Comment: @ennuikiller,yah, But how to catch these records in the variable. I am using aRecord but it store only last record. So this is the main concern.

Comment: 1. That code will probably crash because you never assigned an object's pointer to `myRecords` before the loop, so you're sending `stringByAppendingString:` to a random pointer. 2. Even once you fix that, using `stringByAppendingString:` will simply concatenate all the values together, like “maxsamromjak”. You should use an array here and put the separate string objects into it.

Comment: @Peter thanks for your comments, edited the answer to correct the errors.

Comment: The NSMutableString class doesn't respond to `initWithString:`, and there's no reason to init with a constant empty string in the first place. You can just use `[[NSMutableString alloc] init]` here. (You also need to release that sooner or later.) But then you're still concatenating into a single string rather than collecting a bunch of strings, one per value.

Comment: @Peter - yes I know all that .... didnt want to allo-init the NSMutableString since I didn't want to worry about releasing it....also didn't want to write out the code to populate the array, please feel free to do so in your own answer :)